# Inserting Hyperlink in JavaFx TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to insert HyperLink with text "Remove" in all rows of a column. Only TabelView row will be inserted when clicked on a button. The hyperlink also get inserted but not for all rows. It automatically get blank cell for previous row if next row data is added. Screenshot:
[image]

The hyperlink listener will be created to remove selected row if clicked on it.

This method is called when user click on a button, here i am creating the link:

```
public void SalesAdd(ActionEvent actionEvent){


    if(quantity.getText().isEmpty()){
        quantity.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
        return;
    }
    String name = comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String batch = batchno.getText();
    String exp = expDate.getText();
    int qty = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
    Double mrp1 = Double.valueOf(mrp.getText());
    Double amt = Double.valueOf(amount.getText());
    Double mrpAmount = mrp1*qty;

    PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String> namePro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("name");
    PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Integer> qtyPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Integer>("qty");
    PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String> expPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("exp");
    PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String> batchPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("batch");
    PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Double> mrpPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Double>("mrp");
    PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Double> amtPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Double>("amt");
    PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Hyperlink> rmbutton = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Hyperlink>("rbutton");

    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(namePro);
    qtyColumn.setCellValueFactory(qtyPro);
    expColumn.setCellValueFactory(expPro);
    batchColumn.setCellValueFactory(batchPro);
    mrpColumn.setCellValueFactory(mrpPro);
    amtColumn.setCellValueFactory(amtPro);
    removeRowColumn.setCellValueFactory(rmbutton);



    for(TableData data:tableData){
        if(data.getName()==comboBox.getEditor().getText() || data.getName() == comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString()){
            common.dialogAlert("Already in Table!","Already in the Table!","Already Exist,Please change the quantity!");
            return;
        }

    }

    tableData.add(new TableData(name,batch,exp,qty,mrp1,mrpAmount, rbutton));
    tableView.setItems(tableData);

    clearInput();
    calctotal();


}
```

The TableData Class:

```
public class TableData extends ActionEvent {
private final SimpleStringProperty name;
private final SimpleStringProperty batch;
private final SimpleStringProperty exp;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty qty;
private final SimpleDoubleProperty mrp;
private final SimpleDoubleProperty amt;
private final Hyperlink rbutton;

public Hyperlink getRbutton() {
    return rbutton;
}

public TableData(String name, String batch,
                 String exp, int qty, Double mrp, Double amt, Hyperlink rbutton) {
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.batch = new SimpleStringProperty(batch);
    this.exp = new SimpleStringProperty(exp);
    this.qty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(qty);
    this.mrp = new SimpleDoubleProperty(mrp);
    this.amt = new SimpleDoubleProperty(amt);
    this.rbutton = rbutton;
    this.amt.bind(this.qty.multiply(this.mrp));


}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}

public String getBatch() {
    return batch.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty batchProperty() {
    return batch;
}

public void setBatch(String batch) {
    this.batch.set(batch);
}

public String getExp() {
    return exp.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty expProperty() {
    return exp;
}

public void setExp(String exp) {
    this.exp.set(exp);
}

public int getQty() {
    return qty.get();
}

public SimpleIntegerProperty qtyProperty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty.set(qty);
}

public double getMrp() {
    return mrp.get();
}

public SimpleDoubleProperty mrpProperty() {
    return mrp;
}

public void setMrp(double mrp) {
    this.mrp.set(mrp);
}

public double getAmt() {
    return amt.get();
}

public SimpleDoubleProperty amtProperty() {
    return amt;
}

public void setAmt(double amt) {
    this.amt.set(amt);
}
```

}

How do i add this same HyperLink for every row in a column?

Comment: I guess you use the same `HyperLink` object for all of the rows, which will not work as a `Node` shall not be added twice to the Scene graph (that's why only the last added row displays the hyperlink). For every `TableData` object you shall have a separate `HyperLink` object. I also don't understand why your data model extends `ActionEvent`. Here you can find a good article how to insert `HyperLink`s to a `TableView`: http://www.superglobals.net/create-hyperlink-cell-in-javafx-tableview/

Comment: private Hyperlink rbutton = new Hyperlink();rbutton=new Hyperlink("Remove"); works but now Listener not working? The Listener: rbutton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Clicked");
            }
        });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including UI elements in the item class is seldom a good idea (also extending `ActionEvent` seems unnecessary). The link works independent form any item value, therefore it should't use one. Instead use a cell that displays a link when it's non-empty:

```
public class RemoveCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Void> {

    private final Hyperlink link;

    public RemoveCell() {
        link = new Hyperlink("Remove");
        link.setOnAction(evt -> {
            // remove row item from tableview
            getTableView().getItems().remove(getTableRow().getIndex());
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setGraphic(empty ? null : link);
    }

}
```

This cell does not take any data. Instead the link is displayed only for non-empty cells (`setGraphic(empty ? null : link);`). When the `onAction` event of the `Hyperlink` is triggered, the data available from the `TableCell` is used to remove the corresponding element from the `TableView` that contains the cell. Additional code could be added to the body of the lambda expression in case additional operations need to be done on the removal of a item.

---

Do not use a `cellValueFactory` for the `removeRowColumn` (choosing `Void` as value type only allows for `null` values), instead just use a `cellFactory` creating `RemoveCell`s:

```
removeRowColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new RemoveCell<>());
```

---

BTW: You seem to be recreating the `cellValueFactory`s on a button click inserting a single new item. It would be a better idea to do this just once for the whole table instead of once per inserted table row.

Comment: I am new to java. Can you please explain how this is working? I never write code like this :( . Also i have a Method that calculating another row. How do i call that method after removing a row?

Comment: @rpo: What you're asking about in your comment is basically a tutorial. This is out of the scope of an answer. A more specific question than *"How is this working?"* may be answerable or at least I could post some links for further reading. [The *Cell Factories*  section here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) could shed some light on the `Cell`/`cellFactory` concept.